# Setting Environment Variable in gitlab-ci.yml in script

Tags: gitlab-ci

Please help me in converting below written GitHub Action to Gitlab CI script. I am new to scripting in Gitlab.

From Github documentation I could understand that the below written line is for setting the value of environment variable. But I couldn't find any resource for setting environment variable in Gitlab.

```
run: >
     DISPLAY=:0 xvfb-run -s '-screen 0 1024x768x24' julia --project=monorepo -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.test("GLMakie", coverage=true)'
     && echo "TESTS_SUCCESSFUL=true" >> $GITHUB_ENV
```

Comment: what do you want to do with the environment variable, use it in the same job, or pass it on to another job?

Comment: I want to use it in the same job. I have found that we can set variable in variables section. But how to set them within script section ?

Answer (score 15, accepted):

There are multiple ways to set environment variables, and it depends on what you want to achieve:

1. use it within the same job
2. use it in another job

### Use it within the same job

In Bash or other Shells you can set an environment variable via `export` - in your case it would look like:

```yaml
job:
  script:
    - DISPLAY=:0 xvfb-run -s '-screen 0 1024x768x24' julia --project=monorepo -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.test("GLMakie", coverage=true)' && export TESTS_SUCCESSFUL=true
    - echo $TESTS_SUCCESSFUL #verification that it is set and can be used within the same job
```

### Use it within another job

To handover variables to another job you need to define an `artifact:report:dotenv`. It is a file which can contain a list of key-value-pairs which will be injected as Environment variable in the follow up jobs.

The structure of the file looks like:

```
KEY1=VALUE1
KEY2=VALUE2
```

and the definition in the `.gitlab-ci.yml` looks like

```yaml
job:
  # ...
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: <path to file>
```

and in your case this would look like

```yaml
job:
  script:
    - DISPLAY=:0 xvfb-run -s '-screen 0 1024x768x24' julia --project=monorepo -e 'using Pkg; Pkg.test("GLMakie", coverage=true)' && echo "TESTS_SUCCESSFUL=true" >> build.env
  artifacts:
    reports:
      dotenv: build.env

job2:
  needs: ["job"]
  script:
    - echo $TESTS_SUCCESSFUL
```

see https://docs.gitlab.com/ee/ci/variables/#pass-an-environment-variable-to-another-job for further information.

Comment: Just a footnote: variables created using a "dotenv" artifact can be used within another job's `script`.  The values won't be available for use in other places like `variables` and `rules` sections.